# Differentiate items loading to list vs scroll event Xamarin forms listview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my code that can successfully detect scroll up or down:

```
 MyListView.ItemAppearing += async (object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var currentIdx = CurrentList.IndexOf((MyClass)e.Item);

            if (currentIdx > _lastItemAppearedIdx)
                ShowChopped();
            else
                ShowFull();

            _lastItemAppearedIdx = CurrentList.IndexOf((MyClass)e.Item);
        };
```

What is working is the following: Items get added to the list, then once i start scrolling it works fine where `ShowChopped`and `ShowFull` are methods with animations that just makes a simple animation to either half the size of an object or make it full. This works fine, but if i however click a new category that changes the content in the list, ItemAppearing gets triggered of course and `ShowChopped`and `ShowFull` are called even though i only want it called during a scrollevent.

How would i be able to differentiate a scroll to a item collection change? I have only tried this on iOS.

Updated code:

```
public class ListView_iOS : ListViewRenderer
{
    private IDisposable _offsetObserver;
    private double _prevYOffset;
    private IListView _myListView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement is IListView)
            _offsetObserver = Control.AddObserver("contentOffset",
                         Foundation.NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, HandleAction);
    }

    private static bool CloseTo(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x - y) < 0.1;
    }

    private void HandleAction(Foundation.NSObservedChange obj)
    {
        var effectiveY = Math.Max(Control.ContentOffset.Y, 0);
        if (!CloseTo(effectiveY, _prevYOffset) && Element is IListView)
        {
            var myList = Element as IListView;
            myList.IsScrolling = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted an answer and I think it can solve your problem.

Comment: I have modified my answer, please try this and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate items loading from list scrolling by

1  adding the code `if (EmployeeView.IsScrolling)` within `ItemAppearing` method.

2  adding the code `EmployeeView.IsScrolling = false;` within any function you write to change the appearing of items without scrolling action, for example, when you add items or change category.

And the  `EmployeeView.IsScrolling` value is set from listview renderer.

So the code is like:

NativeListView.cs

```
public class NativeListView : ListView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty
            IsScrollingProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsScrolling),
                typeof(bool), typeof(NativeListView), false);

        public bool IsScrolling
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsScrollingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsScrollingProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

NativeAndroidListViewRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeListView), typeof(NativeAndroidListViewRenderer))]
namespace App2.Droid
{
    public class NativeAndroidListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public NativeAndroidListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement is NativeListView)
                Control.Scroll += Control_Scroll;
        }
        private void Control_Scroll(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            var myList = Element as NativeListView;
            myList.IsScrolling = true;
        }

    }
}
```

NativeiOSListViewRenderer.cs

```
    private IDisposable _offsetObserver;
    private double _prevYOffset;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement is NativeListView)
            _offsetObserver = Control.AddObserver("contentOffset",
                         Foundation.NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, HandleAction);
    }

    private void HandleAction(Foundation.NSObservedChange obj)
    {
        var effectiveY = Math.Max(Control.ContentOffset.Y, 0);
        if (!CloseTo(effectiveY, _prevYOffset) && Element is NativeListView)
        {
            var myList = Element as NativeListView;

            myList.IsScrolling = true;
            _prevYOffset = effectiveY;
        }
    }
    private static bool CloseTo(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x - y) < 0.1;
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing && _offsetObserver != null)
        {
            _offsetObserver.Dispose();
            _offsetObserver = null;
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace App2
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<String> employeeList = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddButtion.Clicked += AddButtion_Clicked;
            DelButtion.Clicked += DelButtion_Clicked;
            EmployeeView.ItemsSource = employeeList;

            EmployeeView.ItemAppearing += async (object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (EmployeeView.IsScrolling) {
                    await DisplayAlert("ItemAppearing", e.Item + " row is appearing", "OK");
                    Console.WriteLine("ItemAppearing!!!!!!!!!!");
                }
            };

        }

        private void AddButtion_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            employeeList.Add("Mr. Mono"+ count++);

            EmployeeView.IsScrolling = false;
        }

        private void DelButtion_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (employeeList.Count > 0) {
                employeeList.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            EmployeeView.IsScrolling = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And you can get the full code of the demo in https://github.com/lemontreexf123/test

Comment: Seems to work for Android but i am currently doing this project for iOS

Comment: The solution for iOS is similar as Android. You just have to do the rendering code for iOS project. And you can refer to this 
 https://criticalhittech.com/2017/11/14/observing-listview-scrolling-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I added that code now but it still cannot seperate an actual scrolling vs itemsappearing. see "updated code" on the post to see the ios part.

Comment: Have you overrided the Dispose() method as the reference shows ? 
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            if (disposing && _offsetObserver != null)
            {
                _offsetObserver.Dispose();
                _offsetObserver = null;
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry, as I donnot have the testing device for iOS. So as to iOS, I can only give the suggestion.

Comment: And you need to update the value of _prevYOffset to effectiveY using:   _prevYOffset = effectiveY;

Comment: I added that but still does not work. u cannot use ios simulator to debug?

Comment: I edited my answer to add the iOS renderer, and it works all right on the simulator of iOS8

Comment: I also updated my code on github, you can download to run the demo  https://github.com/lemontreexf123/test

Comment: Still does not work. When list is changed due to added items or new collectionchanged. The animation is run which is inside the if isScrolling.

Comment: Would you please share the code related to the list changing and item adding? So that it would be easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: You can solve it by adding EmployeeView.IsScrolling = false; in the function where you add items or change to new collection. To test it, I added on "Add" button and one "Delete" button. And in my demo, you can add items by clicking "Add" button, and then scroll the list.  I also updated my code on github, you can download and run the demo https://github.com/lemontreexf123/test

Comment: Glad it helped! and please feel free to ask if there is still any issue.